# Software or web-app to test browser loading speed (independently from network speed)

Tags: windows, web-apps, web-browser, firefox, benchmarking

I've noticed that Firefox has been feeling a bit slow lately.  Setting up a clean profile shows that **it certainly is not Firefox itself**.  Without any extensions installed, Firefox is *blazingly* fast.

Clearly, some of my extensions are slowing it down.  The typical procedure is to disable half of the extensions, check the speed, disable half of the remaining half, check the speed, ad nauseum.

But how to reliably check the speed?  That's where this SE comes in to play.

Is there any Windows software or web-apps that allow me to accurately check browser speed?

Simply loading a bunch of sites a few times doesn't yield consistent results (although doing this scores of times may).  There is too much variability due to multiple levels and types of caching and variances in internet traffic.

What software or web-app will yield useful results?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thank you for the excellent improvement to the title! :-)